How to solve this error "E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-ament-python"
I am using ubuntu 22.04 and ros2 humble. While I am working with a python package and tried to install the package: ament_python but I' am getting the error "E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-ament-python"  How to solve this problem?

That package might be a deppendencie of the package you are trying to use.
Try to install that package:
Use sudo apt install ros-humble-ament-python

I have also tried to install by using this command. But it shows the same error

try to verify if that the package name is the correct one

$ sudo apt install ros-humble-ament-python
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-ament-python
It is the output

Do you have ros humble correctly installed ?
